# Binary zeros in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Tags: windows-10, hosts-file

The file `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on my Windows 10 machine contains 43 binary 0 and nothing else. I did not edit the file in past. The modification time is a day ago. The machine has not been rebooted and no special activity was done at that time.

Do you have any idea what could add binary zeroes to the hosts file and why?

Comment: I'm which program did you see that? Any screenshot. Did you open that file as administrator?

Comment: @Biswapriyo: any program that is able to show binary data show the same. I use https://sourceforge.net/projects/hexplorer/ but I think it does not matter. The file is read only for me, so I can read it without administator's priviliges. When I open it as administrator than I see 43 binary zeros as well

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. After checking the file modification date I suspect it was caused by a Windows update...
By the way: there was a copy named hosts~ which I restored and fixed it...

Comment: Well, it might be Windows update. It was easy to correct when I found but I am still curious what was the reason. Windows update is an option and I suspect Pulse Secure that I use to connect VPN.

Comment: Also have Pulse "Secure" Connect and the same error. But no backup hosts file. Seems to be the culprit. OP, do you have Pulse VPN?